# jquery function is not sending the value on page load

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm sending a value from from my jQuery function to my body, but it seems the jQuery is not sending the value. I want to fire the following jQuery function when my page loads:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src='http://cdn.bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect/downloads/jstz-1.0.4.min.js'></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){  
                var tz = jstz.determine(); // Determines the time zone of the browser client 
                jQuery('body').load('index.php?session_name='+tz.name());
            });
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
```

**index.php:**

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_GET['session_name'])) {$_SESSION['session_name'] = $_GET['session_name'];} 
echo $_SESSION['session_name'];
```

..............
  ..............

Comment: did you make sure there is a value in tz. COuld you place an alert statement and verify the value ?

Comment: Try to put your code out of `$(document).ready`.

Comment: @codeinzone I am sure there is value in tz. Or even if i remove it and put some manual value, then also it won'nt work

Comment: If the code you posted is the whole `index.php` file, of course it won't work - is it so?

Comment: PHP GET gets the value from url so when you do JQuery.load the page has the data but your url does not have any GET request due to which the session will never set.

Comment: @moonwave99 Not whole file.

Comment: @RicardoLohmann I removed and tested but still the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP `GET` gets the value from the URL, so when you use `jQuery.load`, the page has the data but your URL does not have any `GET` request data, due to which, the session will never be set.

If you want to set your session in that way, just redirect the page to the URL you want and the session will be set.

So, instead of doing this:

> jQuery('body').load('index.php?session_name='+tz.name());

Redirect to your page with get values:

> window.location = 'index.php?session_name='+tz.name();

The better way to do it using jQuery is to send the request to the page asynchronously so you don't have to reload the page.

The AJAX way at its simplest:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "index.php",
  data: { session_name: tz.name() }
}).done(function( msg ) {
 // alert( "Session Saved: " + msg );
  console.log(msg);
});
```

And your PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['session_name'])) {$_SESSION['session_name'] = $_POST['session_name'];} 
echo $_SESSION['session_name'];
```

Comment: I can you update your answer to send the request  to timestamp.php page using ajax, in this page i will set the session value.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sending that parameter as a `POST` instead? It would be something like this:

```
$("body").load("index.php", {param1:value, param2:value, etc.})
```